# What kind of travel charger adapter needed when traveling from India to Australia?

Tags: india, australia, power

I am traveling from India to Australia next month. Can anyone please tell me which kind of adapter I should buy? will the product listed below help? or do I need to have a product which performs step up or step down also?

http://www.amazon.in/dp/B01DU9KHSW?psc=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both India and Australia use 240V, so **you do not need a step up/down transformer**.

However, **you will need an adaptor**, since the Australia/NZ "Type I" plug is not compatible with Indian plugs and is used virtually nowhere else: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/AS/NZS_3112

Adaptors are widely available in Australia, including supermarkets and convenience stores, but hard to find outside Australia. However, some fancier multi-plug adapters have rotating pins so they work in Australia as well.

Comment: They're widely available on Aliexpress if needed.

Comment: Should I buy the product given in the link?

Comment: The pins appear to rotate, so yes, that would likely work in Aus/NZ.

Comment: @AvijitDasgupta Please accept the answer (click on the check mark) if it works for you!